# How to aggregate distinct array field in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have this schema

```
const GroupSchema = new Schema({
  id: { type: String },
  users: [{ type: Number }],
  status: { type: Boolean }
},
  {
    timestamps: true
  });
```

I try to aggregate distinct users value sorted by created date.
Example

```
 {
    "users": [1111, 2222],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-09-30T10:51:33.058Z"
    }
}
    {
        "users": [1111, 2222],
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2020-09-29T10:51:33.058Z"
        }
    }
```

I try with :

```
Group.aggregate([
        { "$sort": { "createdAt": -1 } },
        { $group : { _id : "$users" }}, //, created : { $last : "created" }
        { $match : { users : {$in : [1111] }  }}
    ])
```

I expect

```
 {
"users": [1111, 2222],
"createdAt": {
    "$date": "2020-09-30T10:51:33.058Z"
}
}
```

how can i solve?
Thanks.

Comment: can you please add your expected result.

Comment: I want to filter by distinct users field, in this example data I expect the object with the high data
2020-09-30T10:51

Comment: ok but it would be better if you add your expected result as per your documents.

Comment: Ok I update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` your condition
- `$sort` by createdAt date
- `$group` by users array and get latest document in latestDoc
- `$replaceWith` to replace latestDoc in root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { users: { $in: [1111] } } },
  { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$users",
      latestDoc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$latestDoc" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ek8Wpjjhkqn)

Comment: It looks perfect.
I deepen the documentation thanks.